# Applying InputAdornment to MUI AutoComplete removes the options list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I built an AutoComplete component that looks like this:
[image: AutoComplete 1]

```
<Autocomplete
  freeSolo
  size="small"
  id="filter-locks-autocomplete"
  options={json_list ? json_list : []}
  groupBy={(option) => option.lock.building}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => (option.name)}
  inputValue={inputValue}
  onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => setInputValue(newInputValue)}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="standard"
      label={'lock'}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <Search sx={{ color: "black", fontSize: 20, marginLeft: "2px" }} />
            {params.InputProps.startAdornment}
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

However, the list of options do no longer appear when clicking inside the box.
If I remove the InputProps from `<TextField />` like so:

```
<Autocomplete
  freeSolo
  size="small"
  id="filter-locks-autocomplete"
  options={json_list ? json_list : []}
  groupBy={(option) => option.lock.building}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
  inputValue={inputValue}
  onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => setInputValue(newInputValue)}
  ListboxProps={{ sx: { zIndex: 1500 } }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} variant="standard" label={"lock name"} />
  )}
/>;
```

the list of options show as expected.

Is there a way I can add an inputAdornment (just a search icon) to AutoComplete component without removing the Options list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here I found the solution, you can try following code

```
<Autocomplete
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        renderInput={params => {
          return (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="standard"
              label="Multiple values"
              placeholder="Favorites"
              fullWidth
              InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                startAdornment: (
                  <>
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      <SearchIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                    {params.InputProps.startAdornment}
                  </>
                )
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
```

It is working fine. you can also check here in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bug-on-addornments-cjxp7)

for more details check this [Github material-ui issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/19479)

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm.
I guess the main thing was to add 
`...params.InputProps`
in the InputProps